# My Xonar audio card has disappeared upon installing Nvidia card (980 GTX). What can I do to restore it?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, sound

I've installed a brand new GTX 980 and my Xonar audio card (plugged in!) has suddenly disappeared (I'm using one HDMI and DVI port for my two displays).

In order to listen to something I had to re-enable onboard audio, but I would want to use my Xonar, not the rubbish onboard solution.

Any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently was just a wire making contact to the audio card. Everything is now ok... what a kultz!